# Is there a built-in way or plugin to get Jenkins to produce SHA256 hashes for my artifacts?

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-plugins, sha256

My new corporate overlords require that I have a SHA256 hash of each artifact on the customer portal. Of course, I can generate this myself or do it in build script or Makefile, but this feels like the sort of thing Jenkins would be able to do.

Comment: Take a look at the [Fingerprint plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Fingerprint) which takes a md5sum and tracks which projects that version is used in. Meaning you can track a file across multiple pipelines or application sets.

Comment: All I've been able to find is this feature request which is still Open: [https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25808](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25808)

Answer (score 7):

If your builds are running on Unix/Linux, from your Pipeline/Jenkinsfile, you can shell out to `sha256sum`:

```
sha256sum = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "sha256sum '${fileName}'")
```

If your builds are running on Windows, you can shell out to `Get-FileHash` (I haven't tested this):

```
sha256sum = powershell(
  returnStdout: true, 
  script: "Get-FileHash -Algorithm sha256 -Path '${fileName}' | Select -ExpandProperty Hash"
)
```

Comment: This works, but the answer by Emmanuel Osimosu is superior

Answer (score 4):

You can use the jenkins utilty step: `sha256`

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/

```
def hash = sha256 file: 'myfile.txt'
```

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer?

Comment: @enanone because the `sha256` step did not exist at the time this question was asked (in 2015) or answered (in 2017).  The `sha256` step was added in May 2021.

Comment: Oh that's neat @jayhendren. However, it should be marked as the accepted answer now, since most developers that arrive to this question will be in 2021 or later ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the Jenkins Fingerprint Plugin ([link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Fingerprint+Plugin)). It can generate MD5 hashes for your build artefacts, and show those in the Jenkins UI. Unfortunately it doesn't generate SHA256 hashes for your artefacts.